# Dealing with slightly overfull \hbox's

Tags: line-breaking, typography, context-mkiv, letterspacing

Generally, how do you deal with lines that are slightly overhung, when microtypography is already enabled, and there's no way of hyphenating the hanging word and no desire to put it on the next line, leaving ugly whitespaces (especially if the word on the first line of the paragraph)?

Here's an example with two hanging words:

[image: Example of overhanging lines]

I can think of two ways out:

- Margin tweaking: I make line width slightly larger.
- Negative tracking: I decrease letterspacing in the relevant line.

Are there any other methods within given constrains? Which one is a better practice?

**EDIT**: I was able to implement the negative tracking in ConTeXt with `\kerncharacters` command, and it looks quite nice:

[image: Fixed overhung text]

```
% ConTeXt code
\setuppapersize[A5]
\setupbackgrounds[text] [rightframe=on,framecolor=red,rulethickness=0.1pt]

\setupalign[hz,hanging] % microtypography enabled
\definefontfeature[default][default][protrusion=quality,expansion=quality]

\definetypeface[mainface][rm][specserif][Linux Libertine O] [default]
\setupbodyfont[mainface,14pt]

\mainlanguage[russian]
\setupindenting[yes,medium,first]

\starttext
{ \kerncharacters[-0.02] Здесь будет длинный-предлинный текст, \mbox{в~коем}} никак нельзя перенести строку. 
Запрещено {\kerncharacters[-0.01] разрывать телефонные номера, например, \mbox{(000)1234-5678}}, многозначные числа и дефисные написания.
\stoptext
```

Comment: I try to rephrase at this point. In some cases, I simply ignore the bad box. (If it is not obvious or I'm not working on what will be the final, printed version, for example.)

Comment: Note that microtypography is only fully supported by pdfTeX. LuaTeX and XeTeX have more support than they used to, but not as much as pdfTeX. One of them (Lua?) has significantly better support than the other (Xe?). See the `microtype`'s manual for details. I'm assuming that ConTeXt's support will be the same as LuaTeX's. Also, note that 14pt font on A5 is likely to generate problems of this sort with reasonable frequency. And remember that microtypography works best when using font-specific settings. Generic settings must needs be fairly conservative.

Comment: It may be possible to automate the kerncharacters trick. I remember seeing a ConTeXt demo on Arabic typesetting where such optimizations were performed after TeX had done the linebreaking. I don't remember where I saw that example. You may try searching the mailing list archives or asking on the ConTeXt mailing list.

Comment: @cfr: assuming I cannot edit the text. And font/page settings were selected for the purpose of demonstration only, of course: I realize that such occurrences would be relatively infrequent at proper size settings, but they still hurt the eye, and I encountered four of just those in 20-page document before asking the question

Comment: @Aditya: oh, that would be gold! I'll try to find it; and if you do, I'll be very grateful

Comment: (Off-topic suggestion, I know.) Rewriting is also often a very good idea. Of course it is not always possible or reasonable to rewrite/revise, but sometimes a bad over- or underfull paragraph can be improved both visually and semantically by a simple revision.

Comment: @The_Keeper: After a quick search, one reference that I can find is Sec 3.3 of [this tugboat article](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb31-2/tb98hamid.pdf). It may be a good idea to ask about this on the context mailing list

Comment: @Aditya: I've read through the article and unfortunately found no sense in how it deals with tracking. I've posted [my question at mailman.ntg.nl](https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2016/084029.html) (for over a day now), and I've yet to receive an answer. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You could combine the slight negative kerning which you already discovered with extreme shrinking in the font expansion.

```
\setuppapersize[A5]
\setupbackgrounds[text] [rightframe=on,framecolor=red,rulethickness=0.1pt]

\setupfontexpansion
  [extremeshrink]
  [stretch=2,shrink=4,step=.5,vector=quality,factor=1]

\setupalign[hz,hanging] % microtypography enabled
\definefontfeature[default][default][protrusion=quality,expansion=extremeshrink]

\definetypeface[mainface][rm][specserif][Linux Libertine O] [default]
\setupbodyfont[mainface,14pt]

\mainlanguage[russian]
\setupindenting[yes,medium,first]

\definecharacterkerning [shrinkkern] [factor=-.01]
\setcharacterkerning [shrinkkern]

\starttext
Здесь будет длинный-предлинный текст, \mbox{в~коем} никак нельзя перенести строку. 
Запрещено разрывать телефонные номера, например, \mbox{(000)1234-5678}, многозначные числа и дефисные написания.
\stoptext
```